# Powershell to move text files from one folder to another

Tags: powershell

I have a folder that is having multiple subfolders, each folder have around 50 subfolders containing Text Files I want to move file from one folder to another without opening each and every subfolder.
there are two kind of files 1. BSEG and 2. BKPF

I want to move files that are starting with BSEG in folder called BSEG and files starting from BKPF in a folder called BKPF

the code I am using for BSEG files is

```
 Move-Item D:\Company\SAP\JAN\"BSEG"*.txt D:\Company\BSEG
```

this code works but I have to write update code for each subfolder , I want help to modify this code so it looks for all subfolders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell uses -recurse to accomplish this. Give this a shot.  The -recurse piece tells it to hit each sub folder then pipe the output to the move item. It is worth noting that this will not grab the folder structure, just the files, and it will also fail if you try to move files with identical names.

```
 Get-ChildItem D:\Company\SAP\JAN\"BSEG"*.txt -recurse | Move-Item -Destination D:\Company\BSEG
```

Answer (score 1):

[dfundako](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5464747/dfundako) has the half of it. `Move-Item` will not go into sub folders. Using `Get-ChildItem` with the `-Recurse` switch will help get you the files you want to move.

You also have two different sets of files to move. Never repeat code that you need to reuse. So lets have a simple `foreach` loop with both of your file sets. This works well since you are moving files of the same prefix into their own folders.

```
foreach($fileType in $fileTypes){
    Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Company\SAP\JAN\ -Filter "$fileType*.txt" -Recurse | 
        Move-Item -Destination D:\Company\$fileType
}
```